# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define issue

Tags: android, eclipse

i had 4 packages

actionbarsherlock-
Cropper-
google-play-services_lib-
HDWallPaperWithAdmob

and when i run my app this msg appears to me

```
Error: Error parsing /Users/omar/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error: Error parsing /Users/omar/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
[2015-07-06 03:52:52 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2015-07-06 03:52:52 - HDWallPaperWithAdmob] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

i purchased this app i can attach link of download 
thanks for ur reply :)

Comment: try adding this in your dependency com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0

Comment: how i add it to my dependency

Comment: In build. XML file under dependencies section